# How to resolve graphql payload size?

Tags: payload, graphql-java, netflix-dgs

I have a graphql payload which is more than 8KB which exceeds the graphql payload size limitation. I would need suggestion on how can I handle this payload to pass through. I tried to use Graphql APQ, but that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!